# Complex numbers through scanf in C

Tags: c

I have problem with following fragment of code:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 3;

    complex_t t[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double x, y;
        printf("Enter complex number: ");
        scanf("%f %f", &x, &y);
        t[i].re = x;
        t[i].im = y;
    }
}
```

When I am trying to pass x, and y to the program, it doesn't change value, and is 0.00000.
Can you help me?

Comment: Turning on warnings in your compiler will reveal that `%f` is not a correct conversion specification for `double`. Use `%lf`. In the future, always provide a [mre] when asking debugging questions.

Answer (score 6):

You've declared `x` and `y` as doubles, but then went on to use the format specifier for floats (`%f`). So the end result is reading them in as if they were regular floats, then jamming the result into a double leaving you with unexpected values when trying to actually use them.

You need to use the format specifier specifically for doubles (`%lf`) here.

```
scanf("%lf %lf", &x, &y);
```

See [format string specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Format_string_specifications) for more information about different format specifiers.